# Creating jsonb from multiple column

Tags: json, postgresql, stored-procedures, jsonb

I have problems to create jsonb through Postgres 10. I need to extract the value in columns and construct a json format output. I managed to extract the value but having problem to construct it into JSON format

```
P|61||||^^||^^|U||||||||||||||||||||||||||<CR>
O|61|15^1^15|KK4002259|GLU^Glucose (GOD-POD Method)^^
R|170|AST^Aspartate Aminotransferase^^F|22.657989^^^^
R|171|ALP^Alkaline phosphatase^^F|107.636995^^^^
R|172|TP^Total Protein^^F|85.245151^^^^
R|173|TG^Triglycerides^^F|1.348633^^^^
R|174|HDL^HDL-Cholesterol^^F|1.238458^^^^
R|175|CHOL^Total Cholesterol^^F|5.073630^^^^
R|176|UA^Uric Acid^^F|309.705876^^^^
R|177|BUN^Urea^^F|4.412234^^^^
```

Above is my input file which happen in multiple row

Currently my code is below.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION azintin(p_filenm character varying, p_instcd character varying, p_brhcd character varying, p_deptcd character varying, p_trxcd character varying, p_msg text)
 RETURNS jsonb
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
DECLARE
    v_respcd    text;   
    v_respmsg   aft_intarcbox.respond_message%type; 
    v_cnt       INT = 0;
    v_msgar     text[];
    v_msgln     text;
    v_crln      char(2) := chr(13)||chr(10);
    v_msgtyp    character varying(3);
    v_flag      character varying;
    v_result    json;
    macres      azt_macres%rowtype;


BEGIN   

    v_msgar := string_to_array(p_msg, '<STX>');
    
    IF p_trxcd = 'AZ0001' then
    
        -- Loop thru the message array
        FOREACH v_msgln IN ARRAY v_msgar 
        LOOP
                
            IF v_msgtyp='R' THEN
          
                v_flag := split_part(v_msgln,'|',2);

                macres.analyzer_test_full_desc := UPPER((string_to_array(split_part(v_msgln,'|',3),'^'))[2]);
                macres.data_reading := (string_to_array(split_part(v_msgln,'|',4),'^'))[1];

              SELECT jsonb_build_object(macres.analyzer_test_full_desc,macres.data_reading)
                       into v_result from azt_macres;
```

currently my `v_result` output is like this

```json
{"AST": 22.657989}
```

i would to create a json look like this

```json
{"AST": 22.657989, "ALP": 107.636995, "TP":85.245151, "TG":1.348633}
```

Comment: Is the input one long string or multiple rows?

Comment: the input is on multiple rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the input is an array containing one item per row, you can use SQL aggregation to achieve this. There is no need to use a FOR loop.

```
select jsonb_object_agg(split_part(items[3], '^', 1), split_part(items[3], '^', 2))
from (
  select string_to_array(element, '|') as items
  from unnest(v_msgar) as t(element)
) t   
where items[1] = 'R'
```

Inside the function it would be something like this:

```
  ...

  v_msgar := ....; -- put the items into the array

  select jsonb_object_agg(split_part(items[3], '^', 1), split_part(items[3], '^', 2))
     into v_result  
  from (
    select string_to_array(element, '|') as items
    from unnest(v_msgar) as t(element)
  ) t   
  where items[1] = 'R';

  ...
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=a951a085583406ea257a1cf768749831)